# Android different Row layout only for first row in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I am making an **Custom listview** with **Custom Adapter** extending **BaseAdapter**. Now I want to set a different **layout** only for first row and another **layout** for all other rows. I am using this code but it sets the **special layout** for **1st row** and also repeats it after every 5/6 rows. How can I fix it and can set it only for 1st row and another layout for all other rows.

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<News> newsList;
    private Typeface customBanglaFont;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> newsList){
        this.context = context;
        this.newsList = newsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return newsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return newsList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder=null;

        if(row == null){
            if(position == 0){
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single_big_view,viewGroup,false);
            }
            else{
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single_default,viewGroup,false);
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        if (imageLoader == null){
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        }

        final News news = newsList.get(position);
        customBanglaFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(viewGroup.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/SolaimanLipi.ttf");
        holder.newsTitleView.setTypeface(customBanglaFont);
        holder.newsTitleView.setText(news.getTitle());
        holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(news.getFeaturedImgSrc(), imageLoader);

        return row;
    }
}

/**
 * Custom View Holder Class
 * @author Tonmoy
 *
 */
class ViewHolder{

    TextView newsTitleView;
    NetworkImageView thumbNail;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        newsTitleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the Header functionality already built into ListView for this specific thing.

The docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29

or a SO question:
[Using ListView : How to add a header view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978359/using-listview-how-to-add-a-header-view)

Comment: So at last It is solved!!! I used Header view and it worked perfectly after some other little customization!!! thanks a lot @Booger

Answer (score 0):

your attempting is wrong. Your way you will be able to inflate just one layout. In fact, after the method returns the first time, `convertView is not null`. To fix quickly you could override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`. This way you will get `convertView`s eqaul to the return value of `getViewTypeCount`, or you could just add the first item as header view for the `ListView`

Comment: thanks. can you suggest me some examples? I cant understand it clearly