# How can i have a ListView inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, android-nestedscrollview

I have created an app with a page that need to load content dynamically from web service. I want to have listview that can scroll together with a linear layout inside NestedScrollView. But when the contents is loaded to the listview, it doesn't stretch to its full height.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myquestionth.myquestionth10.Profile2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:background="#BBBBBB" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Media heading"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis."
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#70bcf5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have some searched about scrollview cannot be nested.
This is an example i want according to my layout designing from Google play review page. What the method they use? Suggest me if i do something wrong. Many thanks.

[image]

Here is what i want.

[image]

Comment: fix the height of the listview.Or the bestway is to use coordinatorlayout and recyclerview.Refer [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I would suggest you 2 ways to solve that problem:

1) Try to make LinearLayout a header of your ListView. Note that header should be inflated as it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7978397/3921451).

2) You mentioned that you use NestedScrollView, so maybe you should also try to replace ListView inside <s>Nested</s>ScrollView with LinearLayout, as wise people suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing), adding row views in loop similar to how your adapter works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

on Lollipop onwards you can use

```
yourtListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

This enable or disable nested scrolling for this view
if you need backwards compatibility with older version of the OS you'll have to use the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this code, if you want to make listview expand in a nestedscrollview.
Pass the listview reference to the function at the end of creating listview.

```
private static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add a ListView below a Linear Layout and inside a ScrollView, I would suggest to put everything inside the ListView.

Yes you can.

Implement (override) following method on your adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // One view to Header
    // One view to filter options ("most helpful first" and "Options")
    // One view to comments
    private final static int VIEW_HEADER = 0;
    private final static int VIEW_OPTIONS = 1;
    private final static int VIEW_COMMENTS = 2;
    private final static int VIEW_TYPE_MAX = 3;

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount () {
        // It will return 3 since I have 3 different types of VIEW
        return VIEW_TYPE_MAX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return VIEW_HEADER;
        else if (position == 1)
            return VIEW_OPTIONS;
        else
            return VIEW_COMMENTS;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            if(getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_HEADER)
                // Inflate HEADER Layout
            else if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_OPTIONS)
                // Inflate Options Layout
            else
                // Inflate comments Layout
        }

        // Fill the view contents according to its type
        ....
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Android will re-use the views. However Android will re-use views of the same type always.

Comment: Thanks Guiherme i will try this.

Comment: You are welcome.. Try Alex Pepper answer as well... it seems simpler