# Issues with ScrollView and setting layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

Here I'm new to android development. Don't mind if something isn't clear.

I did enough research on this issue, before marking this as **duplicate** please update the solution.

Here I'm adding an image with arrangement of layouts what I want to implement here.

Here the `listView` is being shown as only 1 item. If I scroll, all the items will be scrolled in the shown in this height.

[image: sample image]

Here my `xml` structure is

```
<LinearLayout>(parent)
     <ScrollView>
          <LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout>
                weight: __
                -----------
               </LinearLayout>
               <ListView>
                   h:match_parent
                   w:wrap_content
                   weight:__
               </ListView>
               <LinearLayout>
                   weight:__
                --------------
               </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting numbers of data sets from DB and have to show those sets in middle of the both `LinearLayouts`. For now I'm using `ListView` but seems impossible to use here as my expectation.

Please suggest whether I can I perform in `ListView` here or how can I use numbers of `LinearLayout` blocks for each dataset?

**Update**
This is what I expect as shown in the pic.

[image: sample_layout]

Comment: didn't understand all can u explain more

Comment: I've updated the the question, I want to show the data sets in middle of the 2 `linearLayout` which is I'm getting from DB.

Comment: check my below ans @snsingh i hope it helps

Comment: See if this helps : [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view and this should help [link]http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/03/android-listview-into-scrollview-issue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout>(parent)
     <NestedScrollView>
          <LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout>                    
                w:wrap_content
                h:wrap_content
               </LinearLayout>
               <ListView>
                   w:match_p__arent
                   h:match_p__arent
                   weight:1
                   NestedScroll:true
               </ListView>
               <LinearLayout>
                   w:match_p__arent
                   h:match_p__arent
                   weight:1 
               </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
     </NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this case, scrolling in `listView` works fine, but the `scrollView` isn't being scrolled.

Comment: @SNSingh use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView**

Comment: @SNSingh check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634023/how-can-i-have-a-listview-inside-a-nestedscrollview

Comment: Thanks, now both are working fine, but now the `height` of `listView` is just as of 1 item. what if I want to increase height?

Answer (score 1):

You need this method for your ListView

```
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView target_Listview, int limit) // LIMIT 0 FOR SHOWING ALLL CONTENTS
{
    if (limit == 0) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = target_Listview.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {

            int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                //                if(itemPos < 4)
                //                {
                View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, target_Listview);
                item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                Log.e("" + itemPos, "" + item.getMeasuredHeight());
                totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
                //                }
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = target_Listview.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);

            // Set list height.
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = target_Listview.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
            target_Listview.setLayoutParams(params);
            target_Listview.requestLayout();

            //  return true;

        }
        else {

        }
    }
    else {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = target_Listview.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {

            int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                if (itemPos < limit) {
                    View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, target_Listview);
                    item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    Log.e("" + itemPos, "" + item.getMeasuredHeight());
                    totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = target_Listview.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);

            // Set list height.
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = target_Listview.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
            target_Listview.setLayoutParams(params);
            target_Listview.requestLayout();
        }


    }
}
```

After setting adapter on `ListView` Just call the method and Pass your `ListView` in the parameters with your list size as second parameter.

`One Suggestion from my side` : You should use `RecyclerView` Instead of `listview` . Just need to write one line for that after setting up everything(adapter etc)

```
recyclerView.HasFixedSize();
```

Hope my answer will help.

Comment: Thank @parambir , now the size is adjusted.

Comment: Your welcome @SNSingh Please Mark answer as accepted if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Might need more clarification on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.

If the `ListView` is supposed to be longer and to scroll through more items on the list, I might recommend using the `RecyclerView`. Its a little bit more setup, but allows for a lot more complex layouts to be created based off the concept.

There are a lot of great references to learn the ways of `RecyclerView` if you want to search further:

- this one might help you setup the solution to your problem

  - [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)
- Android Developer website tutorial for `RecyclerView`

  - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html
- Post from Code Path that helped me supplement all of it together.

  - https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: thanks for the response, but I've to implement in `listView`

Comment: Is there a reason it must be a `ListView`? Just because the setup in your layout file right now has a scroll trap since the `ScrollView` and the `ListView` are both scrollable. A `RecyclerView` could help you get around that by combining everything into one big scrollable list.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout>   
      <LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout>
            weight: __
            -----------
           </LinearLayout>
           <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView>
               h:match_parent
               w:wrap_content
               weight:__
            </ListView>
           </ScrollView>
           <LinearLayout>
               weight:__
            --------------
           </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `listView` itself is having scrolling properties, why to add `scrollView` just for listView.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

I have tried in my Android studio and mine is working i am able to scroll view .mine is little bit deffrent  then you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dp"

            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/hello" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Listview itself having a scrolling behaviour no need to add scrollview.

Comment: the `listView` itself is having scrolling properties, I want to scroll whole `linearlayout` and middle of both the `listView` should be scrolled.

Comment: I've updated with a sample image, this is what I want to implement

Comment: SORRY  FOR MISS UNDERSTANDING