# Android: create listview with date as header and a total counts as footer

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have to create a listview in which there will be a date as header , then some list stuffs of daily views and at footer there will be total views of particular date.

Like this:

## Date:dd/mm/yyyy

### type 1 : 5

### type 2 : 4

### type 3 : 1

.
.
.

## Today's total types: 10..

Here everything will be fetched from the sqlite database so please kindly suggest me something related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is unclear. How are you categorizing/calculating daily views here?

Comment: @SudipPodder its from the web service, so he will just fetch the data to the server, no more algo for that

Comment: I was actually confusing with the 'view' term. never mind, probably he got his answer in the answer section provided by Evin_1 :)

Comment: @SudipPodder actually view is just for example it means there are different lists I will use like, for example there are 5 types of songs, in song type 1 there will be 10 songs, type 2 15 songs,.... and in total of everyday there will be total songs of all types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

---

Use the **addHeaderView** and **addFooterView** methods of the ListView.

[Using ListView : How to add a header view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978359/using-listview-how-to-add-a-header-view)

[How to add a footer in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-a-footer-in-listview)

---

Overriding **getViewTypeCount()** and **getItemViewType()** of your custom adapter.

[getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter)