# How to add title for ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I have created tabbed activity with `ViewPager` Contain two tab,tab one Contain `EditText` and tab two Contain `ListView` ,When you write something in `EditText` and click Save the text is pass to `ListView`, I want to add an title for `ListView`. How do I do this?

my fragment_one.java file:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

SendMessage SM;
ViewPager viewPager;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button btnPassData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    final EditText inData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inMessage);

    btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SM.sendData(inData.getText().toString().trim());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });

}

interface SendMessage {
    void sendData(String message);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        SM = (SendMessage) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
    }
}
```

}

my fragment_two.xml file:`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="store.exercise.com.store.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding `addHeaderView` to your list. You can do it by `listView.addHeaderView(textView);`

Comment: You can view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978359/using-listview-how-to-add-a-header-view) thread, it may solve your problem

Comment: Add like this `View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.title_layout, null);
            mListView.addHeaderView(header);` .

Comment: Hello friend You seem to have experience in Android programming, I have a problem and I want you to solve this problem. I have already posted my problem in stackoverflow but I can not find the right solution. Can you help me?