# ListView in ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, listview, scrollview

Of course a `ListView` in a `ScrollView` is problematic since the `ScrollView` wouldn't receive scroll gestures which are performed inside the `ListView` . So I thought about a solution like this: The `ListView` itself should have the height of the sum of the heights of all its elements such that scrolling inside the `ListView` is impossible. Thus, scroll gestures are always passed to the `ScrollView`. Is this somehow possible (I'd like to see some XML code)?

Note: I want to have more `View`s in the `ScrollView` than just my `ListView`. Otherwise I could just omit the `ScrollView` and directly take a `ListView`.

Example of the content of my `ScrollView`:

```
    TextView
    Item 1 of my ListView
    Item 2 of my ListView
    Item 3 of my ListView
    Item 4 of my ListView
    Item 5 of my ListView
    ...
    Item n of my ListView
    EditText
    TextView
    TextView
    Button
```

Since the number of items in the `ListView` might be very high I have to use a `ScrollView` in order to let the user see all `View`s. Omitting the `ListView` and just hardcoding the Items of the `ListView` into the `ScrollView` is not possible because the number of items in the list is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: Can you not use a list view and provide header and footer views to this?

Comment: Can this be done in a nice XML based way? I don't want to do it with ugly case differentiation in java.

Comment: Getting a listview inside a scrollview will create a new array of problems unless you know what you're doing (think about it, two scrollable views fighting to scroll…) It is doable, but less than amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the ScrollView, and add a Header to your ListView  that contains one TextView and a Footer that is a FrameLayout (or similar) containing the EditText, the TextViews (both) and the Button. For more information about how to do that, see [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838921/android-listview-addheaderview-nullpointerexception-for-predefined-views/7839013#7839013).

Or use the getItemType() method as described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row).