# I would like to add a header for set of data?

Tags: android, xml

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WNUW.png)

*I would like to have a header on top of each set of data
For example : id,apple,quantity,category and importance
.This is my xml code for this screen:                                                     *

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff59d"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">




    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Product Id"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/product_id"
        >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/product_name"

        />

    <TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Product Category"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/product_category"

    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/product_quantity"

        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Importance"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/product_Importance"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want a header on top of each item? Or a header for the set of data (Table Header)?

Comment: on the set of data

Comment: You can probably find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7839013/3834912)